# Rails mailer fails to deliver

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails

When I'm using password recovery in Rails, I get this in the development log:

```
Sent mail to me@gmail.com (1024ms)
Date: Sat, 21 Jul 2012 15:24:35 +0700
From: me@gmail.com
Reply-To: me@gmail.com
To: me@gmail.com
Message-ID: <500a67432a8c0_221a25cc491863578@mybox.mail>
Subject: subj
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

base64-encoded stuff here...
```

But the mail is never actually delivered. However when I'm sending mail directly through the sendmail, it works fine:

```
echo 'this is a test' | mail -s test_email me@gmail.com
```

What could be wrong? I'm using Rails 3.2.3 with the latest devise version (I guess devise has nothing to do with it since it forms the message alright, but still).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you told your development environment to actually deliver mail?  Normally, that sort of thing is turned off in development specifically because you don't normally *want* to deliver mail in development.

Comment: Oh my god, is it so simple? :D